SAS calling external process with network path
On SAS Windows, I have a SAS script calling an external .bat file. I use the following:
%SYSEXEC("\\mymachine\order\mypath\running.bat");
which does not recognise the path and default to a C:\ path
if I use - but I would prefer not to - the following
%SYSEXEC("D:\mypath\running.bat");
then it works and my .bat file get executed
any hints on how to use the \mymachine path??
thanks
edits after some comments below; a round about way we just found was to add
pushd "%~dp0"
at the start of the external .bat script - it seem to create a temporary mapped drive pointing to the network path to run the batch.

If UNC paths are not supported then you cannot use them.

Are you running SAS locally? Can you run e.g. %SYSEXEC "NET USE";?

Thanks @Therkel for the suggestion; I tried using NET USE within the %SYSEXEC like
%SYSEXEC("NET USE \mymachine\order\mypath\running.bat"); was that the idea? it did not work unfortunately :-(

From your edit, sounds like the problem is the .bat script, not SAS.  Does it work when you test without SAS, i.e. from command prompt submit: \mymachine\order\mypath\running.bat ?

yes the .bat script works when I run it on its own - thanks @Quentin

Sounds like a WINDOWS issue, not a SAS issue.  It is not letting you execute a program referenced via a UNC instead of a drive letter.  If you don't know if the path is mapped you could try reading in the output of the net use windows command a check if the sharename mentioned in the UNC path is mounted anywhere.

Does the real path contain spaces?  Make sure that the string you pass to WINDOWS has quote characters around the path.   %SYSEXEC("""\\mymachine\order\mypath\running.bat""");

%SYSEXEC is a statement and does not need parenthesis and generally no double quotes either unless the OS path contains spaces.  Try %SYSEXEC NET USE P: \\mymachine\order\mypath followed by %SYSEXEC P:\running.bat

@richard: post your comment as answer so I can accept it

Reiterating:
From the docs:

Comparisons
The %SYSEXEC statement is analogous to the X statement and the X windowing environment command. However, unlike the X statement and the X windowing environment command, host commands invoked with %SYSEXEC should not be enclosed in quotation marks.

So, %SYSEXEC is a statement and does not need parenthesis and generally no double quotes either, unless the OS path contains spaces -- in such a case you may experience hair-thinning as you start dealing with " and SAS double-double quote expressions and potential OS double quote needs within the %SYSEXEC command shell.
Try the following:
%SYSEXEC NET USE P: \\mymachine\order\mypath
%SYSEXEC P:\running.bat

You can set the active drive and folder of the session with
%SYSEXEC NET USE P: \\mymachine\order\mypath
%SYSEXEC P:
%SYSEXEC CD \
%SYSEXEC .\running.bat

If you are comfortable with your Windows install, you can also use PUSHD to set the drive and folder in one command.

This is the message I get when I run a command using infile PIPE runnning a SAS program from network path.  The message is referring to the default directory of SAS program and is coming from CMD.EXE
Stderr output:
'\\filesrv\path\path\path\study-data'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.

This is the command I am running that does not use the CMD default directory
NOTE: The infile DUMMY is:
      Unnamed Pipe Access Device,
      PROCESS=robocopy /MOV /NP filesrv\path\path\path\study-data\ZZ9999 filesrv\path\path\path\study-data\ZZ9999\20240903T122332,
      RECFM=V,LRECL=32767

If I want to run something like a SAS program from the Current directory, I can do that with PowerShell which is happy enough with network drives.
Stderr output:
'\\filesrv\path\path\path\study-data'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
NOTE: The infile DUMMY is:
      Unnamed Pipe Access Device,
      PROCESS=powershell.exe -command "& { Set-Location '\\filesrv\path\path\path\study-data\XX9999\coding-programs' ; ;ls ; Start-Process -Filepath 'E:\SASHome\SASFoundation\9.4\sas.exe' -ArgumentList '-sysin .\code-XX9999.sas' -PassThru -Wait ;ls 
      }",
      RECFM=V,LRECL=32767


Those are message about your current working directory, not the path to the program file you are trying to execute.
